# How to know what a function returns in C# without visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I'm currently working on a C# project and i can't run it on VS since a particular CMS (Tridion) is used.
nevertheless, I try to find out how i can debug some functions.

For instance a function returns a list of strings:

```
public List<string> FilesWithCompt () 
{
List<string> files = new List<string>();    

// instructions
return files;

}
```

In my view i try to display what my list contains :

```
<div class="definitions">

<%= FilesWithCompt () %>
</div>
```

What is displayed on my page:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Because you are returning an Object.  toString() is implicitely called, which just returns the object type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It displays type information. Basically it just calls `files.ToString()` and it returns list type.

You need to use such code:

```
<% foreach(string item in FilesWithCompt()){%>
      <%= item %>
<%} %>
```